# jQuery Vertical Continuous Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm working on an iTunes-like jQuery scroll based on [this script](http://www.websightdesigns.com/tutorials/jquery-itunes-like-content-slider-revisited/).

My version is [here](http://beta.bullsguide.com/entertainment) and is either a lot or not much different depending on how you look at it.

I'm trying to get the items on the right to scroll giving an illusion of continuity. How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the elements (clone().appendTo(...)) and then when you reach one end, get half of the elements from the opposite side and attach them at the end.

Comment: This video (at about 0:20) illustrates the concept: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvOGKoosZ7A ;)